# Mailparse and PHP 5.6.2?

Tags: php, email

Is there a version of Mailparse that works with PHP 5.6.2?  I installed it this morning using `pecl install mailparse` and it placed mailparse.so in what seems to be the wrong location and when I view it in Finder it shows up as a document.

I decided for the heck of it to copy it to the appropriate folder and when I execute the code the uses it I get these messages:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: mailparse: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20121212
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

FYI, I'm not a PHP expert by any stretch.

Answer (score 3):

For php 5.6 and debian first install php5-dev module:

```
apt-get install php5-dev
```

and next use latest build for php5, which is currently:

```
pecl install mailparse-2.1.6
```

If mailparse is already installed you can remove it before any action:

```
pecl uninstall mailparse-2.1.6
```

Comment: Working solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, no, there's not.

http://php.net/manual/en/mailparse.installation.php

> Windows users will enable php_mailparse.dll inside of php.ini in order
>   to use these functions. A DLL for this PECL extension is currently
>   unavailable. See also the building on Windows section.

It seems to be just a matter of compiling, so anyone should be able to compile it and share the DLL, but as far as I know no one has done this.

Answer (score -2):

mailparse hasn't had a release for some years - though the git repo is showing recent work (April 2015). I recently used it for a project, however the version I used had some issues in decoding the display-name & email from a list of not perfectly formatted string of multiple names.

I've since installed [mmucklo/email-parse](https://packagist.org/packages/mmucklo/email-parse) and I'm using that as a native PHP solution on PHP 5.6.